# Unsupported Node.js engine error for @es-joy/jsdoccomment and eslint-plugin-jsdoc

Tags: node.js, eslint, package.json

I'm trying to install or update the npm packages **@es-joy/jsdoccomment** and **eslint-plugin-jsdoc**, but I'm encountering "Unsupported engine" warnings related to the required Node.js versions. Here are the specific warnings:

```
1. npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
   package: '@es-joy/jsdoccomment@0.20.1',
   required: { node: '^12 || ^14 || ^16 || ^17' },
   current: { node: 'v18.18.2', npm: '10.2.1' }
}

2. npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
   package: 'eslint-plugin-jsdoc@37.9.7',
   required: { node: '^12 || ^14 || ^16 || ^17' },
   current: { node: 'v18.18.2', npm: '10.2.1' }
}
```

**Questions:**

- "Is there a way to install these packages with my current Node.js
  version?"
- "Are there any alternative packages that are compatible
  with Node.js v18?"

Comment: use `--force` flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--force` command line flag to install packages within current node version

```
npm install package_name --force
```